# Join or Merge two data-frames based on multiple columns criteria

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two datasets with the following data.

```
maindata = data.frame(eventid=c(1:10),
                  district=c(rep("lucknow",2),rep("allahabad",1),   rep("kanpur", 2)),
                  date = c(rep("2018-01-01", 2), rep("2018-01-02", 1), rep("2018-01-03", 2)))

weather = data.frame(district=c(rep("lucknow", 4), rep("allahabad", 3), rep("kanpur", 3)),
                     date = c(rep("2017-01-01", 4), rep("2017-01-02", 3), rep("2017-01-03", 3)),
                     temperature=c(rep("19.3",2),rep("22.1",1),   rep("24.1", 2)))
```

Few considerations:

1. "date" in each data frame is different, its ok to be like that. MM-DD are sufficient
2. Both datasets have different length - df1 is my main dataset where "temp" should be added
3. The merging must happen over "district" and "date"
4. maindata has district column in lowercase

**What i Tried:** (doing some silly conversions.. will fix them)

```
weather$District<-as.factor(tolower(weather$District))    
weather$Date<-as.Date(as.character(weather$Date),format="%m/%d/%Y")
maindata$md<-strftime(data$createDate, "%m-%d")
weather$mdr<-strftime(weather$Date, "%m-%d")

maindata<-left_join(maindata, weather, by = c("md" = "mdr", "district" = "District"))
```

The **final expected answer** would be something like below in maindata

```
   eventid  district       date    temperature
         1   lucknow 2018-01-01    19.3
         2   lucknow 2018-01-01    19.3
         3 allahabad 2018-01-03    24.1
         4    kanpur 2018-01-03    NA
         5    kanpur 2018-01-02    22.1
         6   lucknow 2018-01-01    19.3
         7   lucknow 2018-01-01    19.3
         8 allahabad 2018-01-03    24.1
         9    kanpur 2018-01-03    NA
        10    kanpur 2018-01-02    22.1
```

Can anybody please help !!!

Comment: `unique(merge(df1,df2[-3],by.x="district",by.y="dist"))`

Comment: @Onyambu.. dates are not same.. year part is different..

Comment: Before edition, i gave a code that gave the expected results. You will find a solution very soon.

Comment: You should really recheck the expected output. there is no row in maindata that contains: `kanpur 2018-01-02`.

Comment: @misuse.. again.. there are lot of codes scattered in my ide.. making mess here.. by it should be fine.. anyways.. on a lighter note.. you have got the context by now... :)

Comment: And now there are a lot of codes scattered in IDEs of at least four people beside you, that were trying to help you. This lack of respect for other peoples time is the reason you received two down votes. Not only that, but I for one, abandoned attempting to provide a solution. I would not be surprised if others share my feelings.

Comment: @misuse.. i understand.. i agree but not disrespect.. i can never be. human errors.. :) anyways... i would like to vote for your solution though..

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this (with the updated data)

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date),
         date1 = format(date, "%d/%m")) %>%
  left_join(df2 %>%
              mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date),
                     date1 = format(date, "%d/%m")), by = c("date1" = "date1", "district" = "dist")) %>%
  select(-date1, - date.y) %>%
  rename(date = date.x) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(eventid))
#output
   eventid       date district  temp
1        1 2017-01-01   dist-1  19.3
2        2 2017-01-01   dist-1  19.3
3        3 2017-01-01   dist-1  19.3
4        4 2017-01-01   dist-1  19.3
5        5 2017-01-02   dist-2  <NA>
6        6 2017-01-02   dist-2  <NA>
7        7 2017-01-02   dist-2  <NA>
8        8 2017-01-03   dist-3 24.10
9        9 2017-01-03   dist-3 24.10
10      10 2017-01-03   dist-3 24.10
```

Convert date in both data frames to `POSIXct`, make a `%d/%m` column and join by it and district, and then clean up

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your logic rules for merging; specifically I don't see how `date` comes in.

It is entirely possible to reproduce your expected output without considering `date` at all, by simply matching `df1$district` with `df2$dist`:

```
library(tidyverse);
left_join(df1, df2, by = c("district" = "dist")) %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    select(-date.y)
#   eventid     date.x district  temp
#1        1 2017-01-01   dist-1  19.3
#2        2 2017-01-01   dist-1  19.3
#3        3 2017-01-01   dist-1  19.3
#4        4 2017-01-01   dist-1  19.3
#5        5 2017-01-02   dist-2  22.1
#6        6 2017-01-02   dist-2  22.1
#7        7 2017-01-02   dist-2  22.1
#8        8 2017-01-03   dist-3 24.10
#9        9 2017-01-03   dist-3 24.10
#10      10 2017-01-03   dist-3 24.10
```

Could you provide sample data that is more representative of what you're trying to do, and where the role/importance of merging on `date` becomes clear?

Comment: Hi Maurits, infact my districts are not in order, dist-3 may come first. I tried that, but it messes up the temperature mapping to the date. here.. in that district on that mm-dd what was the temperature.. in fact df1 has current date and df2 has history date. i am trying to take what what the temperature today based on same dd-mm last year. i now changed the df2.. make a small mistake.. anyhow, thaks for bringing your thought which corrected the question..

Comment: @missuse Yes, I'm a bit confused. Perhaps OP can share a different sample dataset, that is more representative of his problem.

Comment: @AdarshaMurthy Sorry this is still not clear. I can still reproduce your output without considering `date` at all, even after your latest edit. Try it!

Comment: @AdarshaMurthy I think you have updated the df2 but have not updated the expected output?

Comment: @missuse I think you're right; in which case your solution is spot on. I'll remove mine once OP has confirmed.

Comment: @missuse & @ Maurits, you are right.. my whole question what wrong.. my bad, not sure how i mistyped them.. now i have a real clean question .. hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

A quick note - You should really post your trials to the solution before asking for the help in SO.

To the answer -

What you should be using is the `merge` function available by default in R.

After reproducing the data frames that you have provided - try the below chunk of code

```
#Since dates doesn't matter, df2 could be changed to a new df with only temp

df3 <- df2[,c("dist","temp")]
df3 <- unique(df3)

df4 <- merge(df1,df3,by.x = "district",by.y = "dist",all.x = T)
```

The deduplication has been done to avoid creation of numerous rows for each combination of dates in df1 and df2.

`all.x = T` ensures that you're getting a left-join (Where all rows of the df1 are present in your final output)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this.

```
df2[, 2] <- as.numeric(as.character(df2[, 2]))
m1 <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "district", by.y = "dist", all.x = TRUE)[-5]
names(m1)[3] <- "date"
m1 <- unique(m1[, c(2, 3, 1, 4)])
rownames(m1) <- NULL

> m1
   eventid       date district temp
1        1 2017-01-01   dist-1 19.3
2        2 2017-01-01   dist-1 19.3
3        3 2017-01-01   dist-1 19.3
4        4 2017-01-01   dist-1 19.3
5        5 2017-01-02   dist-2 22.1
6        6 2017-01-02   dist-2 22.1
7        7 2017-01-02   dist-2 22.1
8        8 2017-01-03   dist-3 24.1
9        9 2017-01-03   dist-3 24.1
10      10 2017-01-03   dist-3 24.1
```